# Laravel home page gives 404 but index.php works

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel

I'm creating a custom cms in a subfolder of my site. I installed a fresh copy of laravel at www.mysite.com/cms/  <-- application, bundles, public, etc are there.

I can not make a virtual host due to shared hosting but I managed to remove the need for the /public to be in the url by putting

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cms/public/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /cms/public/$1 [L]
```

in the .htaccess file in my cms folder.

The thing is, clean urls works www.mysite.com/cms/public/ shows the Laravel starter page. But www.mysite.com/cms/ gives me a 404 not found error and www.mysite.com/cms/index.php shows the Laravel starter page.

I have set the url array element in application.php to

```
'url' => 'http://www.mysite.com/cms/',
```

and the index element to

```
'index' => '',
```

Has anyone come across this issue?

Answer (score 0):

To use laravel on shared hosting,  I would recommend to try [this](http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=4977).

By the way, in your .htaccess, you are just redirecting to all non-exist request query to index.php in public directory. Because of the fact that, you should access with url.com/public.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but it did not work. All I get is the directory listing.

Comment: There is something wrong. I tried and made work this method a lot of times. What is the content of that directory listing?

Comment: it was just the contents of /cms

Comment: According to the method it shouldn't be any list when you tried to reach cms, because there should be at least index.php and it prevents it. By the way your root directory will be public according to the method, you did it, right?  
/*
- public -> this will be your cms folder  
- - larasys  
- -- application
- -- bundles
- -- laravel
- -- storage
- -- paths.php
- -- artisan
- - index.php*/

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps if you were to upload the contents of your `public` folder into `/cms`, and the other folders into `/cms_system`, you could change the `paths.php` file to reflect this?

So, you'd have this:

```
/cms
    (contents of the public folder, with .htaccess)
/cms_system
    /application
    /bundles
    /laravel
    /storage
    (etc)
```

Your paths would then look like this:

```
$paths['sys'] = 'system';
$paths['bundle'] = 'bundles';
$paths['app'] = 'application';
$paths['storage'] = 'storage';
$paths['public'] = '../cms';
```

I haven't tested this yet, but it should work. Please let me know if there are any problems with it, and will see what can be changed accordingly.

Comment: Did you put your `.htaccess` file back to normal? It should be pointing to the `cms` directory now.

Comment: Ya I removed my .htaccess code posted here since it was not correct

Comment: Perhaps the `REQUEST_URI` part should be taken away, and your rewrite rule should check for `cms` at the beginning of the route? Oh, and have you set your `RewriteBase`?

Comment: To be honest I'm not too familiar with htaccess commands, i've removed the above htaccess since it was incorrect, what would the rewrite base be /cms?